# Separating Tags as Key: true with React Native TextInput

Tags: javascript, react-native

With the React Native TextInput component I get an array by separating the tags with commas.

```
const handleTags = (e: string) => {
  const tags = e.split(',');
  console.log(tags);
}

<TextInput placeholder="Tags" onChangeText={handleTags} />
```

I want to send an output like the one below by making a POST query for the tags I separated with TextInput. How can I send it as key: true?

```
{
"android": true,
"samsung": true,
"phone": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the tags array and put every tag in JSON Object as key and true as it's value like this :-

```
const handleTags = (e: string) => {
  const tags = e.split(',');
  const tagsObject = {};  
  for(let tag of tags){
    tagsObject[tag] = true;
  }
}
```

Now you can send this object in POST request with help of AXIOS or any other package.